# C Allocating array of 500 and more longs

Tags: c, arrays, allocation

So.. I have something like this. It is supposed to create arrays with 10, 20, 50 100 .. up to 5000 random numbers that then sorts with Insertion Sort and prints out how many comparisions and swaps were done .. However, I am getting a runtime exception when I reach 200 numbers large array .. "Access violation writing location 0x00B60000." .. Sometimes I don't even reach 200 and stop right after 10 numbers. I have literally no idea.

```
long *arrayIn;
int *swap_count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), *compare_count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
compare_count = 0;
swap_count = 0;
int i, j;
for (j = 10; j <= 1000; j*=10) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5) {
            int n = i * j;
            arrayIn = malloc(sizeof(long)*n); 
            fill_array(&arrayIn, n);
            InsertionSort(&arrayIn, n, &swap_count, &compare_count);
            print_array(&arrayIn, n, &swap_count, &compare_count);
            compare_count = 0;
            swap_count = 0;
            free(arrayIn);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: ok with this free(arrayIn); I get this " Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun." and I get nowhere. However without it it's "just" "Access violation writing location 0x00780000." but i get up to 200numbers eventually

```
void fill_array(int *arr, int n) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = (RAND_MAX + 1)*rand() + rand();
    }
}

void InsertionSort(int *arr, int n, int *swap_count, int *compare_count) {
int i, j, t;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {   
    (*compare_count)++;
    t = arr[j];
    i = j - 1;
    *swap_count = *swap_count + 2;
    while (i >= 0 && arr[i]>t) {    //tady chybí compare_count inkrementace
        *compare_count = *compare_count + 2;
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        (*swap_count)++;
        i--;
        (*swap_count)++;
    }
    arr[i + 1] = t;
    (*swap_count)++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like insufficient memory, possible memory leaks. Try using Valgrind to detect leaks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks

Comment: Is it possible that either `InsertionSort` or `fill_array` somehow overwrite memory they are not allowed to access? Perhaps they corrupt the memory locations (usually stored just below the allocated memory) that are used to correctly free the block `arrayIn`? Can you show their code?

Comment: Why are you explicitly passing the address of pointer, which itself is a pointer to an address? E.g.  `fill_array(&arrayIn` etc. I probably think oyu should pass just `arrayIn`, which already is a pointer, not `&arrayIn`

Comment: I edited it into the question

Comment: and you are not checking the result of malloc

Comment: @edwardmp As I said below, you actually mentioned it earlier, thanks ;-)

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" into the title. Instead, check the checkmark next to the answer that solved your question.

Comment: @Poody: StackOverflow works by marking an answer as accepted, rather than putting "SOLVED" in the title. If none of the answers were helpful, make an answer yourself and mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Sorry, was used to this from CZ site.. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure your compiler told you what was wrong.

You are passing a `long**` to a function that expects a `int*` at the line

```
fill_array(&arrayIn, n);
```

function prototype is

```
void fill_array(int *arr, int n)
```

Same problem with the other function.  From there, anything can happen.

Always, ALWAYS heed the warnings your compiler gives you.

**MAJOR EDIT**

First - yes, the name of an array is already a pointer.

Second - declare a function prototype at the start of your code; then the compiler will throw you helpful messages which will help you catch these

Third - if you want to pass the address of a simple variable to a function, there is no need for a `malloc`; just use the address of the variable.

Fourth - the `rand()` function returns an integer between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. The code

```
a[i] = (RAND_MAX + 1) * rand() + rand();
```

is a roundabout way of getting

```
a[i] = rand();
```

since `(RAND_MAX + 1)` will overflow and give you zero... If you actually wanted to be able to get a "really big" random number, you would have to do the following:

1) make sure `a` is a `long *` (with the correct prototypes etc)

2) convert the numbers before adding / multiplying:

```
a[i] = (RAND_MAX + 1L) * rand() + rand();
```

might do it - or maybe you need to do some more casting to `(long)`; I can never remember my order of precedence so I usually would do

```
a[i] = ((long)(RAND_MAX) + 1L) * (long)rand() + (long)rand();
```

to be 100% sure.

Putting these and other lessons together, here is an edited version of your code that compiles and runs (I did have to "invent" a `print_array`) - I have written comments where the code needed changing to work. The last point above (making long random numbers) was not taken into account in this code yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// include prototypes - it helps the compiler flag errors:
void fill_array(int *arr, int n);
void InsertionSort(int *arr, int n, int *swap_count, int *compare_count);
void print_array(int *arr, int n, int *swap_count, int *compare_count);

int main(void) {

// change data type to match function
int *arrayIn;

// instead of mallocing, use a fixed location:
int swap_count, compare_count;

// often a good idea to give your pointers a _p name:
int *swap_count_p = &swap_count;
int *compare_count_p = &compare_count;

// the pointer must not be set to zero: it's the CONTENTs that you set to zero
*compare_count_p = 0;
*swap_count_p = 0;

int i, j;
for (j = 10; j <= 1000; j*=10) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5) {
            int n = i * j;
            arrayIn = malloc(sizeof(long)*n); 
            fill_array(arrayIn, n);
            InsertionSort(arrayIn, n, swap_count_p, compare_count_p);
            print_array(arrayIn, n, swap_count_p, compare_count_p);
            swap_count = 0;
            compare_count = 0;
            free(arrayIn);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}

void fill_array(int *arr, int n) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // arr[i] = (RAND_MAX + 1)*rand() + rand(); // causes integer overflow
    arr[i] = rand();
    }
}

void InsertionSort(int *arr, int n, int *swap_count, int *compare_count) {
int i, j, t;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {   
    (*compare_count)++;
    t = arr[j];
    i = j - 1;
    *swap_count = *swap_count + 2;
    while (i >= 0 && arr[i]>t) {    //tady chybí compare_count inkrementace
        *compare_count = *compare_count + 2;
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        (*swap_count)++;
        i--;
        (*swap_count)++;
    }
    arr[i + 1] = t;
    (*swap_count)++;
    }
}

void print_array(int *a, int n, int* sw, int *cc) {
  int ii;
  for(ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    if(ii%20 == 0) printf("\n");
    printf("%d ", a[ii]);
  }
  printf("\n\nThis took %d swaps and %d comparisons\n\n", *sw, *cc);
}
```

Comment: It works. So basically passing array to function using pointer is without the operator, because the name of the array is a pointer itself? I think that's like the 2nd lesson with pointers..
Made my day, thanks

Comment: Check my answer. tl;dr If you are passing a pointer, don't use & in fron of it. If you are passing primitive types (like normal ints) do use the &. And @floris I really wonder why his compiler wasn't complaining.. or it did and you ignored it

Comment: Dayum.. Much appreciate it 2) I do that, just didn't show you. 3) I will try that 4) Good point, I will certainly look at that. It was actually a piece of code given with the task, so .. :D
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the literal value `0` to some pointers. You are also mixing "pointers" with "address-of-pointers"; `&swap_count` gives the address of the pointer, not the address of its value.

First off, no need to malloc here:

```
int *swap_count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)) ..
```

Just make an integer:

```
int swap_coint;
```

Then you don't need to do

```
swap_coint = 0;
```

to *this pointer* (which causes your errors). Doing so on a regular `int` variable is, of course, just fine.

(With the above fixed, `&swap_count` ought to work, so don't change that as well.)

Comment: I need those because I need to work with them inside two other functions

Comment: Yes, but you only have to pass on the *address* of the variable (i.e., `&var`), not the address of a pointer to the variable.

Comment: So I pass it like this InsertionSort(arrayIn, n, swap_count, compare_count);
and inside the function i just use it without '*' ?

Comment: That depends entirely on what other changes you make. IOW, it's not the *only* thing to change that will make it magically work.

Answer (score 0):

As I told in the comments, you are passing the addresses of pointers, which point to an actual value.

With the ampersand prefix (&) you are passing the address of something.
You only use this when you pass a primitive type.

E.g. filling the array by passing an int. But you are passing pointers, so no need to use ampersand.

What's actually happening is that you are looking in the address space of the pointer, not the actual value the pointer points to in the end. This causes various memory conflicts.

Remove all & where you are inputting pointers these lines:

```
fill_array(&arrayIn, n);
InsertionSort(&arrayIn, n, &swap_count, &compare_count);
print_array(&arrayIn, n, &swap_count, &compare_count);
```

So it becomes:

```
fill_array(arrayIn, n);
InsertionSort(arrayIn, n, swap_count, compare_count);
print_array(arrayIn, n, swap_count, compare_count);
```

I also note that you alloc memory for primitive types, which could be done way simpler:

```
int compare_count = 0;
int swap_count = 0;
```

But if you choose to use the last block of code, **DO use** &swap_count and &compare_count since you are passing primitive types, not pointers!

Comment: and change the type of `arrayIn` to `int` since that is how it's declared in the function...

Comment: @Jongware True, but I don't really see the point of allocating memory for primitive types (see final block of code in my answer)

Comment: I think it needs some changes in those functions too, because when I just take out amperesands, it does not work. Let me see..

Comment: Hey @poody read up on this, then you'll understand better what's actually causing these errors. https://study.cs50.net/pointers and https://study.cs50.net/malloc