# How to find memory leaks using valgrind with a C++ program that has been compiled using -g

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I [followed the steps outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks) to find memory leaks in a C++ program that I compiled using `-g`, but the program never terminates, and thus the memory leaks check doesn't end.

Whereas by using the same C++ program this time compiled using `-Os` the valgrind check terminates.

What can I do then?

Comment: `-g` is independent from `-Os`, compile with both. Also `-g` should only add debug informations, so it should not change the behaviour of the program.

Comment: @mch But then why does the valgrind check not terminate with `-g`?

Comment: Does the `-g` program terminate without valgrind?

Comment: @mch  No, but when compiled without `-g` it does terminate with valgrind. What can I do in such case?

Comment: If changing compiler flags and/or running under valgrind changes behaviour, there's probably a bug. You need to figure out what that is first anyway, so try using the debugger. Just attach gdb to your non-terminating `-g` process without using valgrind.