# json_decref() cause memory Invalid write

Tags: c, json

I got some problems when I call json_decref()

```
#include <jansson.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    json_t *aa, *bb, *cc, *dd;

    aa = json_load_file ("/home/cuihaikuo/demo.json", JSON_STRICT, NULL);
    bb = json_array_get (aa, 0); 
    if (bb != NULL) 
        json_decref (bb);
    if (aa != NULL)
        json_decref (aa);

}
```

I use vargrind running the program, it says Invalid write of size 8

```
==2641== Invalid write of size 8
==2641==    at 0x4E4201A: json_delete (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4.7.0)
==2641==    by 0x4006C3: json_decref (in /home/cuihaikuo/chk/test/a)
==2641==    by 0x400721: main (in /home/cuihaikuo/chk/test/a)
==2641==  Address 0x5412438 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==2641==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2641==    by 0x4006C3: json_decref (in /home/cuihaikuo/chk/test/a)
==2641==    by 0x40070E: main (in /home/cuihaikuo/chk/test/a)
```

if I comment out `json_decref (aa);`, it will lead a memory leak, how to explain it and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_array_get()](http://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.10/apiref.html#c.json_array_get) returns a borrowed reference. You must not call [json_decref()](http://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.10/apiref.html#c.json_decref) on the values that are returned as borrowed references, unless you manually call `json_incref()` to increase the reference count. In your minimalistic example, this is not required, so remove the `json_decref (bb);` and the code should work as expected.

However, if you need to use `bb` after you have released `aa`, then call `json_incref (bb);` after `bb = json_array_get (aa, 0);` and later, when you are done using `bb`, you can call `json_decref (bb);`

Also, even though `json_array_get()` doesn't mind being passed a NULL value, it would be nice to check the value of `aa` before using it, so readers of your code doesn't have to double check the manual to see if it is OK not to check `aa` before using it in `json_array_get()`.