# strcpy() in c gives me segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to assign the names to clients in a TCP server, but the `strcpy()` function is giving me a segmentation fault.

```
struct clients{
  int client_fd;
  char* name;
  struct clients* next;
}

struct clients* first;
first->client_fd = 1;
first->name = NULL;
memset(&first->name, 0, sizeof(first->name));
first->name = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
strcpy(first->name, "User");
first->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer `struct clients* first;` doesn't point to any [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)d memory, so trying to access a property on it like `first->client_id = 1` is an uninitialized pointer dereference.

Because behavior is undefined after the dereference, the segmentation fault could occur at `strcpy` (or anywhere else, but `strcpy` is not the culprit). Consider using a tool like [valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989219/6243352) to identify these illegal memory accesses when they occur.

Also,

- the lines:

  ```
    first->name = NULL;
    memset(&first->name, 0, sizeof(first->name));
  ```

  don't really do anything since the `first->name` memory location is subsequently written over. You may omit these.
- `(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));` can just be `malloc(5)`. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, `(char *)` is an unnecessary cast and `100` is too much memory for `"User"`, which only needs 5 characters (one for the null terminator).
- `free` allocated memory to avoid leaks.
- Checking `malloc`'s return value to ensure the memory was successfully allocated is a good idea.
- You can use [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) instead of the `malloc`/`strcpy` pair but the drawback of this is that you might forget that `strdup` allocated memory that needs to be freed.

Here's a re-write (`malloc` return checks omitted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct clients {
    int client_fd;
    char* name;
    struct clients* next;
};

int main(void) {
    struct clients* first = malloc(sizeof(*first));
    first->client_fd = 1;
    first->name = malloc(5);
    strcpy(first->name, "User");
    first->next = NULL;

    printf("%d %s\n", first->client_fd, first->name); // => 1 User

    free(first->name);
    free(first);
    return 0;
}
```