# Function will only properly work if I've printed the values of the attributes

Tags: c

I am trying to create a library for college that handles musical partitions from XML files.
I don't want to get into much detail, but I have a function that creates the partition `score` and another that adds individual notes `score_add_note`.

The prototypes are as follows :

```
score_t* score(size_t tempo, size_t duration, size_t sig, size_t nbInstr)
void score_add_note(score_t* sc, size_t ins, size_t bar, pitch_t p, size_t start, size_t duration)
```

I have also transformed the XML file into a structure that I have made, it is called `e` in this case.

In one occasion, I used these functions like this :

```
score_t* sc = score(atoi(e->at_head->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->next->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->next->next->value));
score_add_note(sc, 0, 0, 60, 0, 6);
```

The attributes are part of the XML structure.

This doesn't work, the `score_add_note` function never stops executing.

However, if I print the values from the attributes to the `score` function beforehand, it works correctly:

```
printf("%d\n", atoi(e->at_head->value));
printf("%d\n", atoi(e->at_head->next->value));
printf("%d\n", atoi(e->at_head->next->next->value));
printf("%d\n", atoi(e->at_head->next->next->next->value));

score_t* sc = score(atoi(e->at_head->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->next->value), atoi(e->at_head->next->next->next->value));
score_add_note(sc, 0, 0, 60, 0, 6);
```

Am I making some mistake or is this a bug in C. If so, is there any way around it?
Btw, I am using gcc as my compiler.

EDIT: 
As asked, here is the `score_add_note` function

```
void score_add_note(score_t* sc, size_t ins, size_t bar, pitch_t p, size_t start, size_t duration){
    if(sc->system[ins].tab[bar] == NULL){
        sc->system[ins].tab[bar] = (bar_t*) malloc (sizeof(bar_t));
        sc->system[ins].tab[bar]->start = start;
        sc->system[ins].tab[bar]->duration = duration;
        sc->system[ins].tab[bar]->pitch = p;
    }else{
        note_t* note = sc->system[ins].tab[bar];
        while(1){
            if(note->next == NULL){
                note->next = (note_t*) malloc (sizeof(note_t));
                note = note->next;
                break;
            } 
            note = note->next;
        }
        note->start = start;
        note->duration = duration;
        note->pitch = p;
    } 
}
```

There is a chance that the function is stuck in an infinite loop, but the arguments are the same in both cases.

This is the `score` function:

```
score_t* score(size_t tempo, size_t duration, size_t sig, size_t nbInstr){
    score_t* sc = (score_t*) malloc (sizeof(score_t));
    sc->tempo = tempo / 60;
    sc->duration = duration;
    sc-> time_sig = sig;
    sc->sys_size = nbInstr;
    sc->system = (staff_t*) malloc (nbInstr * sizeof(staff_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < nbInstr; i++){
        sc->system[i].tab = (bar_t**) malloc (duration * sizeof(bar_t*));
    }
    return sc;
}
```

These are the types I have created:

```
typedef struct note_s{
    size_t start;
    size_t duration;
    pitch_t pitch;
    struct note_s* next;
}note_t;


typedef note_t bar_t;

typedef struct staff_s{
    bar_t** tab;
}staff_t;


struct score_s{
    size_t tempo;
    size_t duration;
    size_t time_sig;
    size_t sys_size;
    staff_t* system;
};
```

Comment: How can anybody determine why "`score_add_note` function never stops executing" if you don't show the definition?

Comment: There isn't a problem with that function. In both cases, that function receives the same attributes. In any case I'll post the function.

Comment: @asbestos_moccasin There’s either a problem with that function, or with the surrounding code. Since the behaviour differs based on seemingly unrelated changes, there’s a high (>99%) chance that your code invokes undefined behaviour. By contrast, the chance of a compiler bug is <0.1%.

Comment: _I don't want to get into much detail_, That's okay, but you have to put in at least as much detail as is needed to address your questions.  If possible, prepare a very small example of code that contains only enough to illustrate the issue you are seeing and edit your post with that example.  ( [mcve] )

Comment: On a side note, please don't use the `_t` suffix for your types. It is a reserved suffix for the C implementations to add new types.

Comment: You don't terminate your list. You never assign `NULL` to `note->next;` (for the newly created note) during adding a node. Probably your `score()` function contains the same bug. But as you don't show us the mandatory MCVE but only some incomplete snippets, we cannot be sure what's wrong.

Comment: @darnir *On a side note, please don't use the _t suffix for your types. It is a reserved suffix for the C implementations to add new types*  Not in C11:  [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)

Comment: I have also added the `score` function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But Section 7.31.10 (Future Directions) essentially reserves the right to add new typedefs to `stdint.h` with the `_t` suffix, which means you should steer clear of it. Not to mention, it is also prohibited in the GNU Lib C Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html 
And is a reserved suffix according to the POSIX specification as well

Comment: @darnir That's only [limited to `[u]int*_t`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.10).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you have a link that my browser won't flag as a "potential security threat"? It's Firefox, and apparently, "Most browsers no longer trust certificates issued by GeoTrust [_et al._]". However, yeah, `_t` is not reserved for the implementation in C, only by POSIX, which many people can go their entire lives without ever using.

Comment: @underscore_d That's the only marked-up HTML version that I'm aware of.  See [**Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) for PDFs or plain text.

Comment: As I guessed, your `score` function has the same problem. You do not initialize any of the pointers in the array you allocate: `sc->system[i].tab = (bar_t**) malloc (duration * sizeof(bar_t*));` You have `duration` pointers that are not initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: BTW: you do not show definition of `score_t`. Please do not expect that we hunt for all the missing information. There is a reason why you shall provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It is to ensure that everything is there.

Answer (score 4):

This code

> ```
>     note_t* note = sc->system[ins].tab[bar];
>     while(1){
>         if(note->next == NULL){
>             note->next = (note_t*) malloc (sizeof(note_t));
>             note = note->next;
>             break;
>         } 
>         note = note->next;
>     }
> ```

never sets `note->next` to `NULL` when creating a new node on the linked list.  You therefore invoke undefined behavior when accessing the list later.

This would be better:

```
    note_t* note = sc->system[ins].tab[bar];
    while (1) {
        if (note->next == NULL){
            note->next = malloc(sizeof *note->next);
            note = note->next;
            note->next = NULL;
            break;
        } 
        note = note->next;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: This is also the case for `sc->system[ins].tab[bar] = (bar_t*) malloc (sizeof(bar_t));` where `next` is neither set to null.

Comment: I've corrected that too but it isn't the problem either.

Comment: @asbestos_moccasin There are likely problems in the code you didn't post, then.  If you're on Linux, try [using Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks) to find memory access problems.

Comment: @asbestos_moccasin I have already mentioned in my first comment that you probable have similar problem in your `score` function. Did you fix that, too?