# Get full stacktrace in Fortran ifort

Tags: fortran, stack-trace, intel-fortran

My Fortran code has a memory issue and since I compiled it with Intels `-traceback` option it will show me:

```
forrtl: severe (41): insufficient virtual memory
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
fleur_MPI          0000000000F00CFC  for_alloc_allocat     Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          0000000000A32BAA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          00000000009E4392  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          00000000008CB602  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          00000000009226F8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          000000000091E051  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          0000000000419967  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          00000000004A9DA0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          00000000004A5350  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          0000000000416BAE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002B75726A7505  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
fleur_MPI          0000000000416AA9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
 Signal           15  detected on PE:           3
```

It only shows me the deepest 12 entries of the stacktrace, which are not very usefull, since they don't have the `-g` option.

How can I increase the length of the stack traces I get? It seems this question is only answered for Java, but not Fortran (or even C).

Comment: Any reason you can't add the `-g` flag to the config as described here https://www.flapw.de/MaX-4.0/documentation/installation/#configure

Comment: The `-g` Flag is set by default. The problem with this part is, that it's automatically generated OpenMP code, which doesn't generate debugging symbols.

Comment: Do you have a core file? If does ulimit -c unlimited and rerunning generate one? Once you have one does stepping up the call tree with a debugger tell you what you need?

Comment: Maybe you could run it with `valgrind`. This has a plethora of options which allow you to do stack-traces, find memory leaks ... and much more. [How do I use valgrind to find memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks)

Comment: Valgrind in not feasible, because the code runs for several hours without valgrind. I also tried to generate coredumps, but they aren't created