# Why won’t valgrind detect a memory leak in a basic program with a leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

My Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char* string = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        printf("my code ran\n");
        return 0;

}
```

I compiled it with:

```
gcc -o mem memErr.c
```

and ran it with

```
valgrind ./mem
```

and

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./mem
```

but my output was

```
(cmd)(base) ~/Documents/c/summerC$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./mem
==65172== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==65172== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL`d, by Julian Seward et al.
==65172== Using Valgrind-3.17.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==65172== Command: ./mem
==65172==
==65172== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff202d0000, 0x8000200d0000) (defined)
==65172== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff202d0000, 0x7fff7ff88000) (defined)
==65172== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff8e23c000, 0x7fffc02d0000) (noaccess)
==65172== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffc02d0000, 0x7fffe2560000) (defined)
==65172== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffe2560000, 0x7fffffe00000) (noaccess)
my code ran
==65172==
==65172== HEAP SUMMARY:
==65172==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==65172==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==65172==
==65172== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==65172==
==65172== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==65172== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why dosn't valgrind report a memory leak here?

Edit:
Based on comments from @dbush and @AJIOB I tried changing the code to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char* string = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(string, "my new code ran");
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0; 
}
```

and compiling with:
`gcc -g -o mem memErr.c`
but the result is the same:

```
(cmd)(base) ~/Documents/c/summerC$ valgrind ./mem
==81073== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==81073== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL`d, by Julian Seward et al.
==81073== Using Valgrind-3.17.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==81073== Command: ./mem
==81073==
==81073== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff202d0000, 0x8000200d0000) (defined)
==81073== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff202d0000, 0x7fff7ff88000) (defined)
==81073== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff8e23c000, 0x7fffc02d0000) (noaccess)
==81073== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffc02d0000, 0x7fffe2560000) (defined)
==81073== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffe2560000, 0x7fffffe00000) (noaccess)
my new code ran
==81073==
==81073== HEAP SUMMARY:
==81073==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==81073==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==81073==
==81073== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==81073==
==81073== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==81073== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Edit:
The issue seems to be a macOS Big Sur compatibility issue with valgrind. My current workaround is using a virtual linux environment with Docker to run valgrind.

Comment: I think, you should look that [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks).

Answer (score 0):

Since the memory returned from `malloc` was never used, the compiler probably optimized the call away.

This line in the valgrind output seems to back that up:

```
total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
```

If you modify the code so that the malloc'ed buffer is used, valgrind should report a leak:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char* string = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(string, "my code ran");
        printf("%s\n", string);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: The OP should check the disassembly. With the default `-O0`  it does not optimize the `malloc` on my side

Answer (score 0):

From [Valgrind Quick start guide](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html): you should compile your program with `-g` flag (debug symbols).

Also, as @dbush user said, you should operate with your string for telling the compiler, that your variable is really required.