# How to create a debugger without using operating system capabilities

Tags: debugging

Recently I get a test task from one company. And one question is:

> Suppose you are given a task to write a simple debugger (for a
>   proprietary operating system) that is capable of setting a break-point
>   in an application and running it. What would be key design decisions
>   you make in such a task?

I think I don't know something but I have absolutely no idea about answer. I understand how debuggers work (INT 3 - should have access to virtual space of debuggie) but I suppose the answer about "proprietary operating system".

Comment: You need to think more generally - `INT 3` is CPU-specific and the question doesn't say anything about what CPU this proprietary OS is running on.

Comment: Hmmm trying to think of a non-proprietary operating system. Not sure what they are getting at either, as an operating system is a suite of applications, some of which you might use in a debugger, but hopefully at a fairly high level of abstraction. Sounds like a HR translation of a very technical question this.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think "proprietary" means that, you cannot modify any part of the operating system.

Comment: @Rafal. Maybe they should have used a different word then, because that isn't what proprietary means and an OS you can't modify any part of is a waste of bits.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I know what proprietary means, I just assumed that this is an imprecise abbreviation of "you do not have a source code and cannot extend the OS for your purposes" and this is a reasonable constraint when you propose such a test task.

Comment: It's a reasonable constraint for an academic exercise, I doubt the role was for that. It's questions like this that prove to me my potential employer isn't one....

Answer (score 1):

This question, as usual at the interview should **make you asking more questions about the system and requirements**.

Does operating system already provide some kind of primitive tracing tool you can use?
What language are tested applications written in?

Some inspection tools, for example valgrind, **[run inspected programs in their own environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1656227/13767)**, which seems a good way to go in your case. The other approach is to **instrument the binary with tracing instructions**, communicating with your debugger - this is probably more suitable and easier to do when your applications run under a VM.