# Program crashes normally but not with Valgrind

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, 64-bit, valgrind

I am trying to debug a piece of assembly program (`x86 64-bit`), and according to the `gdb` info, it crashes when using the following instruction:

```
xorpd  0x1770(%rip),%xmm12        # 0x40337c <S_0x403230>
```

However, it seems to me that memory `0x40337c` is perfectly normal:

```
(gdb) x /10x 0x40337c
0x40337c <S_0x403230>:  0x00000000      0x80000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x40338c <S_0x403240>:  0xf149f2ca      0x00000000      0x746e7973      0x203a7861
0x40339c <S_0x403248+8>:        0x206d626c      0x6d69743c
```

Another wired thing is that, this piece of code crashes everytime when I run it in the command line, as well as inside `gdb`. However, when I debug it in the `valgrind`, it would not crash !

```
☁  src [master] ⚡ valgrind ./a.out 20 reference.dat 0 1 100_100_130_cf_a.of
==18329== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18329== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18329== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18329== Command: ./a.out 20 reference.dat 0 1 100_100_130_cf_a.of
==18329==
MAIN_printInfo:
    grid size      : 100 x 100 x 130 = 1.30 * 10^6 Cells
    nTimeSteps     : 20
    result file    : reference.dat
    action         : nothing
    simulation type: channel flow
    obstacle file  : 100_100_130_cf_a.of

LBM_showGridStatistics:
   nObstacleCells:  498440 nAccelCells:       0 nFluidCells:  801560
  minRho:   1.0000 maxRho:   1.0000 mass: 1.300000e+06
 minU: 0.000000e+00 maxU: 0.000000e+00

LBM_showGridStatistics:
  nObstacleCells:  498440 nAccelCells:       0 nFluidCells:  801560
  minRho:   1.0000 maxRho:   1.0431 mass: 1.300963e+06
  minU: 0.000000e+00 maxU: 1.272361e-02

==18329==
==18329== HEAP SUMMARY:
  ==18329==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==18329==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 428,801,136 bytes allocated
 ==18329==
==18329== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18329==
==18329== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18329== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I uploaded the binary code at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp0t741z3j93yf3/a.out?dl=0) for your reference if you are interest.  The assembly program is actually produced by a binary rewritter, and I used to be able to produce bug-free code. So I believe this may not be a hard-to-debug pointer dereference issue, should be something very easy to fix.. However, I really have no idea where goes wrong, and it seems perfectly normal in the gdb debugging (`x/10x 0x40337`)

So here is my question,

1. given the debug info (`x/10x 0x40337c`), where could possibly go wrong?
2. Why the binary code would not crash in `valgrind`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind [runs your code on a simulated x86 CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656227/how-does-valgrind-work).  Apparently it doesn't simulate alignment checking.

---

128-bit and larger memory operands to SSE instructions always need to be naturally aligned.  (e.g. to a 16B boundary for a 16B load like this one).  The exception is [MOVUPS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVUPS.html) (`_mm_loadu_ps`) (and MOVUPD / MOVDQU).

0x40337c is not 16B aligned, only 4B.  (So it's quite weird that you're using it with XORPD, since I'd expect at least 8B alignment for a `double`).

AVX instructions are the reverse: the default is no alignment required, but VMOVAPS does require alignment.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Now I know better.. Do you have any idea that how should fix this one? Since this pointer (`S_0x403230`) refers to a location in the `.rodata` section, maybe force the 16b alignment for `.rodata` section would work?

Comment: If I remembered correctly, around 1.5 years ago, when I used this binary rewriter and work on the exact same piece of code above, I should somehow make some alignment in the produced assembly code, but I didn't remember the details any more.. I will try to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: @computereasy: Yeah, do whatever you need to do so that your vector constants are aligned, rather than changing your program to use unaligned loads into a tmp register.  It sounds like a bug in your rewriting software if it's not preserving at least the alignment that sections specify.  You can see that with `readelf -S foo.o`.  The `.rodata` section should be part of the text segment, which is usually at least 16B aligned.  `S_0x403230` sounds like the original address was aligned, since the last hex digit is 0.

Comment: Adding the `.align 16` at the beginning of `.rodata` and `.data` section fix the above issue. Thank you so much for your help!